# How to avoid B Class object creation from outside world, and allow through only A Class

Tags: java

How to avoid B Class object creation from outside world, and allow through only A Class ?

I have 2 classes

```
public class A {
    B obj = null;
    public A() {
        obj = new B();
    }        
    public void methodA () {
        obj.methodB();
    }        
    // other methods
}

public class B {
    public void methodB () {
        // some logic            
    }
    //other methods
}

public class Client {
    public static void main (String s[]) {
        // Valid Call            
        A obj = new A();
        obj.methodA();  // Since methodB is called internally

        // Invalid Call , How to restrict this B object creation here ?
        B objB = new B();
        objB.methodB();

    }
}
```

Comment: remove public from public void methodB !!

Comment: Can we check which class is trying to create the object of class B in B class Default Constructor ?

Comment: AFAIK, its not possible to find the class which is trying to create instance of another class, since object creation is in the control of JVM.

Comment: Declare your method package-private : as @Anonymous said remove the keyword public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution, its working ..

```
public class A {

    public static boolean isFromAClass = false;
    B obj = null;

    public A() {
        try {
            isFromAClass = true;
            obj = new B();
            isFromAClass = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("methodA");
        obj.methodB();
    }
    // other methods
}

public class B {

    public B () throws Exception {
        if(!A.isFromAClass) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("methodB");
        // some logic
    }
    //other methods
}

public class Client {

    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception {
        // Valid Call
        A obj = new A();
        obj.methodA();  // Since methodB is called internally

        // Invalid Call , How to restrict this B object creation here ?
        B objB = new B(); // this line throws Exception
        objB.methodB();

    }
}
```

A, B, Client class may be in any package.

using public static boolean isFromAClass = false; field, it is achieved.

Only I need to change, instead od generalized Exception, it should be customized Exception as **OutSideAClassBClassInstanceShouldNotBeCreated**

Comment: Is there any loop hole into the above solution ?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I can think of is to use a inner static class of A: KeyToB with a private constructor, that is needed by B to be instanciated. Therefore, there is only A that can instanciate B, which can be in a different file.

```
public class A {
    B obj = null;
    public A() {
        obj = new B(instance);
    }
    public void methodA() {
        obj.methodB();
    }
    // other methods ..

    //The key to have the right to instanciate B, only visible in A
    private static KeyToB instance = new KeyToB();

    public static class KeyToB{
        private KeyToB() {
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    //The constructor is package visible, it need a non null instance of KeyToB . If someone use new B(null), it will get a RuntimeException
    B(KeyToB instance) {
        if (instance == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("B can only be instanciated by A");
        }
    }
    public void methodB() {     
    }   
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution indeed works. However, I wonder what the use case is. Generally speaking, when one ask himself such a tricky question, it is time to go back to the primary use case and ask whether this question answer is the good answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the class B as an inner class of class A and specify the scope of class B as private

```
class A {
    B b = null;
    public A() {
    b = new B();    
    }
     public void testA() {
       return b.methodB();
     }

    private class B {

         public void methodB () {             
                   // some logic                     
         }  

    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: Inner class is one of the option, but which is not feasible to my implementation. I need these 2 classes in different.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept of `Inner Class`.

`Private` members of the `Outer Class` **(ie Enclosing Class)** is **accessible to all the** `Inner Class` **(ie Enclosed Class)** within it, and **vice-versa**

So let `Class A` be the **Outer Class**, and `Class B` as the `private` **Inner Class**

```
public  class A {

        B obj;

        public A() {

        obj = new B(); 

        }


        private class B {

             public void methodB () {             

             }  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to put both `A` and `B` in the sample package. Then make class `B` public but its constructor `package` access or `protected`:

Class `A` would be:

```
package my;
public class A {}
```

and class `B` would be:

```
package my;
public class B {
   B() {}
}
```

If class `B` is actually not needed outside the package, you can also even make the class itself a package access one.

Answer (score 0):

Put the B class in the same package as A, and make its constructor package-protected. Only the classes from the same package will be able to invoke it.

Comment: but if client is in the same package then, it can create object of class B.

Comment: If the client is in the same package, then it's not the outside world anymore. If you really want to restrict the access to A, make it an inner static class of A and make its constructor private.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `B` a inner (static)  class of `A` with private constructor.

```
class B {

    public A createA() {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }

    public static class A {
        private A() {}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use private static nested class:

```
    public class A {
        private static class B {
            public void methodB () {
                // some logic            
            }
            //other methods
        }

        B obj = null;

        public A() {
            obj = new B();
        }        
        public void methodA () {
            obj.methodB();
         }        
         // other methods
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {

    private class B{

        private B(){

        }       
    }

    public B createB(){
        return new B();
    }

}
```